# dplyr keep missing data

Tags: r, dplyr, na, pipes-filters

I established a connection to an internal Teradata DB.In order to let you know my issue i have provided an exampled below.

What I am trying to do is to filter columns by **my_date** and narrow it down by **my_key**.

But I would like to keep the missing results but somehow the filter drops them within my *my_result*. Again currently the below code drops them if not available. As mentioned within the comments @zx8754 I have tried to add `is.na(my_date)` to the filter but without success. I have also tried `is.empty`, `is.null`, `complete` instead of `collect`.

Any help would be much appreciated.

**Reproducible test**

```
# Create my_df
my_key <- c(1, 2, 3,4)
my_date <- as.Date(c('2018-07-01','2018-08-01','2018-09-01','2018-09-01'))
my_df <- data.frame(my_date, my_key)

# Filter_mydf
my_result <- my_df %>% 
  select (my_date,my_key)%>%
  filter(between(my_date ,as.Date("2018-08-01"),as.Date("2018-09-01")),
         my_key %in% c(1,2,3))%>%
  collect()
```

**my_result**

```
my_date my_key
2018-08-01 2
2018-09-01 3
```

**Desired my_result**

```
my_date my_key
NA 1
2018-08-01 2
2018-09-01 3
```

Comment: Try using is.na? `filter((between(col_date,20180701,20180930) & col_key %in% c(12345,54321)) | is.na(col_date))`

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: Related github post: https://github.com/tidyverse/dplyr/issues/3196

Comment: @zx8754 Thanks but is.na(col_date) lead into the same result without the missing data.

Comment: Provide reproducible data, please. So we can have the same problem as you.

Comment: @zx8754 Sorry, please find a reproducible example within my main question.

Answer (score 0):

Set **my_date** to NA if date is not *between* dates, then filter on **my_key**:

```
# Create my_df
my_df <- data.frame(
  my_date = as.Date(c('2018-07-01','2018-08-01','2018-09-01','2018-09-01')),
  my_key = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5))


library(dplyr)

my_df %>% 
  mutate(my_date = if_else(between(my_date, as.Date("2018-08-01"), as.Date("2018-09-01")) & 
                             my_key %in% c(1, 2, 3), my_date, as.Date(NA))) %>% 
  filter(my_key %in% c(1, 2, 3))

#      my_date my_key
# 1       <NA>      1
# 2 2018-08-01      2
# 3 2018-09-01      3
```